# PhantomJS on AWS Lambda Always Timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, phantomjs

I'm try to create a task on AWS Lambda that create PDF file from PhantomJS then upload it AWS S3 later.

Now, I try to run it on Lambda but it's always Timeout.

My Lambda has 128mb of ram. The runtime is node.js 4.4.3.

This is the error I got from Lambda

```
"errorMessage": "2017-03-01T08:05:56.255Z dfd4cfe8-fe55-11e6-bf24-e7edf412e037 Task timed out after 10.00 seconds"
```

Also these are the log output

```
REPORT RequestId: dfd4cfe8-fe55-11e6-bf24-e7edf412e037  Duration: 10000.08 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 29 MB


2017-03-01T08:05:56.255Z dfd4cfe8-fe55-11e6-bf24-e7edf412e037 Task timed out after 10.00 seconds
```

This is my code.

**Index.js**

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var path = require('path');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

     // Set the path as described here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'];

     // Set the path to the phantomjs binary
     var phantomPath = path.join(__dirname, 'phantomjs_linux-x86_64');

     // Arguments for the phantom script
    var processArgs = [
         path.join(__dirname, 'phantom-script.js'),
         event.url
    ];

    // Launc the child process
    childProcess.execFile(phantomPath, processArgs, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            context.fail(error);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            context.fail(error);
            return;
        }
        context.succeed(stdout);
    });
}
```

**phantom-script.js**

```
 var system = require('system');
 var args = system.args;

 // Example of how to get arguments passed from node script
 // args[0] would be this file's name: phantom-script.js

 const url = "https://google.com";

 system.stdout.write('hello from phantom!');

 console.log("task start, target url = " + url);

 console.time("execute time");
 phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
     console.time("create Page");
     ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
         console.timeEnd("create Page");
         console.time("open website");
         page.open(url).then(function(status) {
             console.timeEnd("open website");
             console.time("render as pdf");
             page.render('google.pdf').then(function() {
                 console.timeEnd("render as pdf");
                 console.log('Page Rendered');
                 ph.exit();

                 // send to s3
                 console.timeEnd("execute time");
             });
         });
     });
 });


 // Send some info node's childProcess' stdout
 system.stdout.write('hello from phantom!')

 phantom.exit();
```

I try to do my work following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645131/how-do-i-run-phantomjs-on-aws-lambda-with-nodejs) but it's not working.

I didn't get any of log from my `phantom-script.js` like it is not trigger but my task always timeout.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, rendering a page as an image, and it seems to time out after attempting to page.render. Same memory, 30 seconds. You figure anything out?

Comment: Actually, just tried using context.getRemainingTimeinMillis() in different parts of my code, to see if I was actually "appropriately" timing out. After a long time I realised I was just hitting max memory with phantomjs, so I doubled to 256mb.

Comment: @svjacob I added the solution that work for me in the answer below. This is work for me. Hope this help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I spend a lot of time on it. I found the package name [Phantomjs-Prebuilt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-prebuilt) that you can install it via `npm`. you have to  do `npm install` on amazon linux instance or docker amazon linux that has node version 4.x (lambda is using node version 4.3). Otherwise it will not work on lambda.

Then, I updated my code like this.

**Index.js**

```
var phantomjs = require('phantomjs-prebuilt')

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var sourceUrl = "https://example.com"
    var program = phantomjs.exec('phantom-script.js', sourceUrl)
    program.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
    program.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
    program.on('exit', code => {
        // do something here after you phantomjs finish.
        return
    })
}
```

**phantom-script.js**

```
var system = require('system')
var args = system.args

// Example of how to get arguments passed from node script
// args[0] would be this file's name: phantom-script.js

var url = args[1] // received sourceUrl value

// Send some info node's childProcess' stdout
system.stdout.write('phantomJS running\r\n')

var webpage = require('webpage').create()

webpage.paperSize = {
    format: 'A4',
    orientation: 'landscape'
}

webpage.open(url, function(status) {
    system.stdout.write('start open page\r\n')
    webpage.render('/tmp/web.pdf', {
        format: 'pdf',
        quality: '100'
    })
    system.stdout.write('finish render page\r\n')
    phantom.exit()
})
```

On lambda the place you can write a file is `/tmp` folder that why i saved the file there.

I'm running this via lambda with 192mb of ram. It's work really fine. I can create a screenshot of webpage that has 500 images with this setting. The most important thing is make sure your lambda is able to connect internet.

FYI, I realize that when phantom-script.js (the file i wrote phantom script in.) has an error your lambda will freeze until it timeout. That's why I always got this response from lambda `Task timed out after 10.00 seconds`.