# How do I install fontconfig on AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, node-html-pdf

This is a continuation of [How do you install phantomjs on AWS lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56795567/61624) I've figured out how to get phantomjs running on an aws lambda, but when I use it to generate pdfs (using the html-pdf nodejs library), the content is missing text.  If I create a docker container that's using `FROM node:10.16.0-jessie` on it, the pdfs render fine.  If I create a docker container using `FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20190508` (which I think is similar to the AWS lambda container), the text is missing on my PDFs.

I've fixed this problem in `amazonlinux:2.0.20190508` by running `yum install fontconfig`.  But, I don't know how to do the equivalent of a `yum install fontconfig` inside a real lambda.  If you look at the link above, you'll see that an answer there *attempts* to provide that information, but for whatever reason, it still doesn't work correctly.  I believe the reason is there's still a missing step on how to get the fontconfig install properly extracted from the `amazonlinux:2.0.20190508` container.

In summary, here is my question: After I run `yum install fontconfig` in `amazonlinux:2.0.20190508`, how do I extract it from the container and package it up so that an AWS Lambda can use it?

By the way, I'm sure there are other answers that seem to be answering this question, but the AWS lambda built-in dependencies change so frequently, none of those answers work anymore.

Comment: Have you tried Lambda layers ?

Comment: May be Lambda Layer can solve your problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @EliyaCohen nope, gave up on it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did this:

1. Create a Docker file with content:

```
    FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20190508
    RUN yum -y install fontconfig freetype
```

and build it as `example:latest`

2. Run docker and mount folder:

```
docker run -v D:\dockerFiles:/mnt --rm -it example:latest
```

3. Found libraries inside docker by path `/lib64`

`libbz2.so.1  libexpat.so.1  libfontconfig.so.1  libfreetype.so.6  libpng15.so.15`

4. Copy it to `/mnt/lib`. Take `lib` from `D:\dockerFiles` and zip folder lib.
5. Create aws lambda layer and add to lambda.